# Ring with gradient in Android

Tags: android, xml, radial-gradients

I want to create a ring with gradient which starts from the inner edge of the ring. I tried to do that in this way but then I get a gradient which starts from the center of the ring.

Picture: http://s1.postimg.org/tw5htbxxb/Untitled_1.jpg
Left picture shows what I want to do and right picture shows what I get from the following code.

```
<shape 
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="20dp" 
    android:thickness="30dp" >

    <gradient 
        android:type="radial"
        android:gradientRadius="100%p"
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="ring"
       android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
       android:thickness="20dp"
       android:useLevel="false" >
    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerY="0.50"
        android:endColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="sweep"/>
</shape>
```